# Removing duplicate values that occur more than N times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with repeat values in column "lid". I want to use Pandas to remove the rows that its value in column "lid" is counted more than 2 times. 
Here is original table:

```
entity  pnb head#   state   lid
ABB001  A03 3   DOWN    A
ABB001  A03 3   DOWN    A
ABB001  A03 3   DOWN    A
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    B
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    B
ABB002  A02 2   DOWN    C
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    D
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    E
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    E
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    E
```

Here is the result:

```
entity  pnb head#   state   lid
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    B
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    B
ABB002  A02 2   DOWN    C
ABB002  A02 4   DOWN    D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 0**
Using `value_counts` and `isin`

```
df[~df.lid.isin(df.lid.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 2].index)]

   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

---

**Option 1**
Better implemented with `np.in1d` and `pd.factorize`

```
lids = df.lid.values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid.values)
df[np.in1d(lids, u[np.bincount(f) <= 2])]

   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid)
df[np.bincount(f)[f] <= 2]

   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

---

For fun demonstration to highlight what @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and I were talking about in the comments.

> Love the bincount one. There should be a np.unique one too, somewhere. – cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ
>
> Yes there is. However, I don't use np.unique because @Jeff informed me that np.unique sorts when you grab counts or index or inverse. pd.factorize does not and is O(n). I've since validated that information. – piRSquared

**Time Test**

```
def bincount_factorize(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid.values)
    return df[np.bincount(f)[f] <= 2]

def bincount_unique(df):
    u, f = np.unique(df.lid.values, return_inverse=True)
    return df[np.bincount(f)[f] <= 2]

def in1d_factorize(df):
    lids = df.lid.values
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid.values)
    return df[np.in1d(lids, u[np.bincount(f) <= 2])]

def transform(df):
    return df[df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size') <= 2]

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000,
           30000, 100000, 300000, 1000000],
    columns=['bincount_factorize', 'bincount_unique',
             'in1d_factorize', 'transform'],
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(d)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import d, {j}'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

res.div(res.min(1), 0)

         bincount_factorize  bincount_unique  in1d_factorize  transform
10                 1.421827         1.000000        1.119577   3.751167
30                 1.008412         1.037297        1.000000   3.072631
100                1.000000         1.531300        1.028267   3.304560
300                1.000000         2.666583        1.182812   3.637235
1000               1.065213         5.563098        1.000000   2.556469
3000               1.024658        10.480027        1.000000   2.238765
10000              1.073403        14.716801        1.000000   1.574780
30000              1.000000        16.387130        1.053180   1.494161
100000             1.000000        18.533078        1.003031   1.369867
300000             1.078129        20.183122        1.000000   1.530698
1000000            1.166800        24.571463        1.000000   1.670423
```

---

```
res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Love the bincount one. There should be a `np.unique` one too, somewhere.

Comment: Yes there is.  However, I don't use `np.unique` because @Jeff informed me that `np.unique` sorts when you grab counts or index or inverse.  `pd.factorize` does not and is `O(n)`.  I've since validated that information.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` + `transform`.

```
df[~df.lid.groupby(df.lid).transform('count').gt(2)]
```

```
   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

---

`transform` gets you a series of counts of the same size.

```
v = df.lid.groupby(df.lid).transform('count')
v

0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    1
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: lid, dtype: int
```

Use that to figure out what rows need to go.

```
~v.gt(2)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: lid, dtype: bool
```

Use the mask to index `df`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size') <= 2]

print (df)
   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    1
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: lid, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size') <= 2)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: lid, dtype: bool
```

Another slowier solution with [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('lid').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2)
print (df)
   entity  pnb  head# state lid
3  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
4  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   B
5  ABB002  A02      2  DOWN   C
6  ABB002  A02      4  DOWN   D
```

**Timings**:

```
#jez1
In [34]: %timeit (df[df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size') <= 2000])
10 loops, best of 3: 57.8 ms per loop

#jez2
In [35]: %timeit df.groupby('lid').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2000)
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ
In [36]: %timeit (df[~df.lid.groupby(df.lid).transform('count').gt(2000)])
10 loops, best of 3: 93.6 ms per loop

#pir1
In [37]: %timeit (df[~df.lid.isin(df.lid.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 2000].index)])
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

#pir2
In [38]: %timeit (pir(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 32.9 ms per loop
```

**Setup**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcde') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': np.random.choice(L, N, p=(0.75,0.0001,0.0005,0.0005,0.2489)),
                   'A':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['A','lid']).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)


print (df[~df.lid.groupby(df.lid).transform('count').gt(2000)])
print (df[df.groupby('lid')['lid'].transform('size') <= 2000])
print (df[~df.lid.isin(df.lid.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 2000].index)])


def pir(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid)
    return df[np.bincount(f)[f] <= 2000]

print (pir(df))
```

**Caveat**

The results do not address performance given the number of groups, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.

Comment: I didn't write it down with speed in mind.  But if we do, you'll want to use `pd.factorize(df.lid.values)` in `pir`

Comment: I get `In [40]: %timeit (pir(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 33.5 ms per loop`

Comment: with `def pir(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.lid.values)
    return df[np.bincount(f)[f] <= 2000]`, so seems it is same here

Comment: Well then I guess it doesn't matter much on larger data (-:

Comment: @piRSquared - Exactly. And I am surprised isin is so slow :(